# jQuery tooltip, default options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to have all my tooltips contained within the body of the document so as to not have them being cut off by other `div` elements and such.

I found this does the trick for example:

```
$('span[type="warningpopup"]').tooltip({ container: $('body') });
```

The issue is that I've got tons of `tooltip()` calls in my views and was wondering if there is a way to instruct jquery UI to always use the body as container by default?

I tried messing around with `$.ui.tooltip.prototype` but could not find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well you can do it, of course, but jQuery UI tooltip doesn't have container option. Plus tooltips are never cut by default. Anyway, just set `$.ui.tooltip.prototype.options.container = document.body`, should work.